# Unable to access mysql db via jmeter JDBC connection configuraition due to Client side certificate

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter, jks

We have created .jks file to access mysqldb to work on jdbc requests and it has client side certificate security as per Dmitri suggestion in few blogs i read that creating .pem file from ppk, from .pem file to jks using open ssl, I did everything and generated .jks file and imported certificate from jmeter>>options>>ssl manager, but it's giving following error message

"Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)"
- if i need to configure keystore configuration and csvdataset config, how to add value(certificate data which is in JKS format) in csv and pass it into variable in keystore configuration, and also do i need to use ${varname} format in keystore configuraiton?
really i did everything still i did not get resolved the problem

i have attached screen shots of jmeter configuration, please help me to get it resolved

Please go to link for jmeter jdbc configuration
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16HjXR-vIn-KvgSUXEzahgl6DZruVLpjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I have posted all the details i have, do you require any specific details, please let me know

Comment: You haven't posted all the details, you have just posted a fragment of an exception message. Without the full stacktrace, we are lacking information about the actual error that occurred.

Comment: Please open drive link shows screen shots of configuration, let me know you need any specific deatails on this, thank you for helping.

Comment: People are unlikely to open links, and that information **must** be in the question itself.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can i add images to this post instead of link.

Comment: You shouldn't post an image, you should post the stacktrace **as text**